# The gevent library is used to implement the coroutine, but the execution is slower

Tags: python, coroutine, gevent

There are five categories, and each category contains multiple TXT files. I need to count the number of occurrences of each word in each file. I want to improve the efficiency of the program through the coroutine. However, the comparison shows that the program slows down after the use of the coroutine. I don't know why. Did I use the coroutine in a wrong way?

Here is the code:

```
import os
import re
import time
from collections import Counter
import gevent

def count_words(content):
words = [word.strip('"') for word in re.split("[\s-]", content) if re.fullmatch("[a-zA-Z']+", word.strip('"'))]
word_count = Counter(words)
return word_count


def process_single_document(folder_name, document_path):
    with open(document_path, mode='r+', encoding='utf8') as f:
        content = f.read()
        word_count = count_words(content)
        content_append = '\n'.join([f'{word} {count}' for word, count in sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[0])])
        f.write(content_append)
        file_name = f'{folder_name}_{os.path.basename(document_path)}'
        return {file_name: sum(word_count.values())}

@timecost
def process_single_folder(folder_path):
    folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
    folder_res = {}
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        folder_res.update(process_single_document(folder_name, file_path))
    print(f'file counts: {len(folder_res)}')
    return folder_res

@timecost
def process_single_folder_coroutine(folder_path):
    folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)
    result = []
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
        res = gevent.spawn(process_single_document, folder_name, file_path)
        result.append(res)
    gevent.joinall(result)
    folder_res = {}
    for res in result:
        folder_res.update(res.value)
    print(f'file counts: {len(folder_res)}')
    return folder_res
```

Here is the result:

```
--- type: athletics ---

file counts: 101

process_single_folder cost time: 7.486446142196655

process_single_folder_coroutine cost time: 8.679980754852295

--- type: cricket ---

file counts: 124

process_single_folder cost time: 10.89174485206604

process_single_folder_coroutine cost time: 11.055976390838623

--- type: football ---

file counts: 265

process_single_folder cost time: 20.97000026702881

process_single_folder_coroutine cost time: 20.88500189781189

--- type: rugby ---

file counts: 147

process_single_folder cost time: 12.401747703552246

process_single_folder_coroutine cost time: 12.073007106781006

--- type: tennis ---

file counts: 100

process_single_folder cost time: 6.553194522857666

process_single_folder_coroutine cost time: 6.651681184768677
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? You are doing a lot of CPU-bound work: [Gevent multicore usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617553/gevent-multicore-usage)

Comment: If both computing and I/O scenarios exist, how do I determine whether I/O-bound or CPU-bound?

Comment: You are splitting, doing regex, counting words, appending, joining ... all that is CPU. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean

Comment: I checked the CPU usage during the execution of a single thread and found that the CPU usage remained about 25%. The ratio seems low.